# Javassist: how to solve a duplicate class exception?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, bytecode, javassist, linkageerror

Using `Javassist` I'm trying to insert a line of code into a method's body. It's a simple modification for a label's text color inside the `intellij-IDE`. I get the following error when trying to do so:

> *Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader @d2cc05a attempted duplicate class definition for com.intellij.ui.components.labels.LinkLabel.
> (com.intellij.ui.components.labels.LinkLabel is in unnamed module of loader com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader @d2cc05a, parent loader 'platform')*

Which implies that the class I am trying to modify is already loaded by the Java class loader (at least I like to think so..).
An example of the code is given below:

```
private static void test() {
        try {
            ClassPool cp = ClassPool.getDefault();
            CtClass cc = cp.get("com.intellij.ui.components.labels.LinkLabel");
            CtMethod cm = cc.getDeclaredMethod("getTextColor");
            cm.insertBefore("System.out.println(\"helloworld\");");

            cc.toClass(); // <--- the problem
        } catch (final Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And for reference, here's the accessed class: [intellij link](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/d2b4f4abbc5af066875402db4250e988aadfcd76/platform/platform-api/src/com/intellij/ui/components/labels/LinkLabel.java)

---

[Rafael Winterhalter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1237575/rafael-winterhalter) commented on a similar issue a couple of years ago ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23336172/adding-an-annotation-to-a-runtime-generated-class-using-javassist/23359661#23359661)). Unfortunately my knowledge with `Javassist` is limiting me in finding a proper solution.

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

---

**UPDATE:** A minimal, repoducible example can be found here: [github link](https://github.com/decod3d/example)

Comment: What are you going to do with the `Class` object you are trying to get by `toClass()` and why do you need it at all? Instead of just explaining **how** you are trying to do something you should better explain **what** you are trying to achieve? Otherwise your question might just be another example of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/309898).

Comment: You have to apply the changes *before* the class has been loaded. Otherwise, you have to specify, which mechanism you intend to use for modifying already loaded code.

Comment: @kriegaex I have updated my question and example to better illustrate what im trying to achieve.

Comment: @Holger my code is loaded before the application is shown. So I have to modify already loaded code. Any tips or simple examples on how to achieve this? My best guess would be to retransform the class?

Comment: Your update still does not explain why you call `cc.toClass()` and how you trigger the retransformation. Do you use `-javaagent` option for the JVM? Are you trying to attach your transformer during runtime? If so, how? I think an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub would be helpful.

Comment: @kriegaex my apologies for not providing a proper explanation. I have updated the question with a minimal example on github.

Comment: I can clone, but not check out your project due to lots of errors like `...KotlinTypeAliasByExpansionShortNameIndex.storage: Filename too long`.

Comment: You also checked in a lot of Gradle and IDEA stuff instead of just source code and build configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is a old question, but it is the top result on google when you search "duplicate class definition javassist" so I might as well share the possible solution.

That problem that you are experiencing is because the class is already loaded into the class pool. You will have to modify/redefine the class before the class is loaded into the class pool.

In your particular problem, you are trying to redefine `com.intellij.ui.components.labels.LinkLabel`. This [class](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/44139df66e8e7e2fe67fbd81df530a29c688e04f/platform/platform-api/src/com/intellij/ui/components/labels/LinkLabel.java#L42) has a static field called `ourVisitedLinks`. This static field will force the `LinkLabel` class to be loaded on the first mentioning of `LinkLabel` class.

When you call `cc.toClass()` then you are essentially making a reference the to `LinkLabel` class and thereby loading the class into the class pool because the static field `ourVisitedLinks` is initialized. The `LinkLabel` class is thereby implicit loaded into the class pool just before you load the modified version of the class.

I admittedly do not understand everything that is going on inside javassist. I just know that `cc.toClass()` will load the class into the class pool preemptively due to the static field being initialized.

You will have to instead call `cc.toClass(SomeNeighbor.class)`. The `SomeNeighbor.class` is a fictive class that I made up for the example. It just have to be a class that is within the same package as the class that you are trying to redefine.

The `LinkLabel` class has the following [neighbors](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/44139df66e8e7e2fe67fbd81df530a29c688e04f/platform/platform-api/src/com/intellij/ui/components/labels) that share the same package `com.intellij.ui.components.labels`:

- ActionLink
- BoldLabel
- DropDownLink
- LinkListener
- SwingActionLink

You can pick any of those 5 classes as a neighbor as long as the class does not have any direct nor transitive static dependency of `LinkLabel`.

This is the corrected code of the example in the question. The github link that was shared in the question is unfortunately not longer accessible, so I can not provide a perfect executable example.

```
private static void test() {
   try {
        ClassPool cp = ClassPool.getDefault();
        CtClass cc = cp.get("com.intellij.ui.components.labels.LinkLabel");
        CtMethod cm = cc.getDeclaredMethod("getTextColor");
        cm.insertBefore("System.out.println(\"helloworld\");");

        cc.toClass(BoldLabel.class); // <--- the correction
    } catch (final Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```